# Example of product of martingales which is not a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega,F,\{F_n\},\mathbb P)$ a filtrated probability space and let $X$ and $Y$ $\{F_n\}$ martingales in $L^2$. I am looking for an example, that $XY$ is a sub martingale but not a martingale.(I know that one can easily show that this product has to be a sub martingale with Jensen's equality, i.e, take $X=Y$, but this attempt does not provide that the product is a martingale aswell..)

Any examples are welcome! (easy ones prefered)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused -- what's your objection to using the $X = Y$ example? Is your objection that you don't know how to show that it isn't a martingale? (It *almost surely* won't be a martingale, after all.)

Comment: I just know $XY$ will be a sub martingal , but this still could be a martingale. So I am actaully looking for an example so that it is not $\ge$ but $>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be a simple random walk on the integers and take $Y_n = X_n$.

Comment: can you help me? I tried this example, but failed.. My attempt: Let $X_i$ i.i.d,$ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = S_n$ , $X_0 :=0$, $\mathbb P(X_i=1)=0.5=\mathbb P(X_i=-1)=$ Then folllows $$E(S_{n+1} \mid F_n )=E(S_{n}^2+2S_n X_{n+1}+X_{n+1}^2 \mid F_n)=S_{n}^2 +2 S_n E(X_{n+1})+E(X_{n+1}^2 )$$ I used independence and measurbility, but $E(X_{n+1})=E(X_{n+1}^2)=0$ and so this is a martingale, but not a submartingale.

Comment: @JohnDoe ?? $E(X_{n+1}^2)=0$, you say?

Comment: @JohnDoe Note that $X_{n+1}^2 = (\pm 1)^2$ is $1$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did eehm or was I missing that $E (X_{n+1}^2)$ should be equal 1?

Comment: ok thanks at both of you!

Answer (score 0):

If $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is a square-integrable martingale then $(X_n^2)_{n\ge 0}$ is a submartingale. It is a martingale if and only if $E((X_{n+1}-X_n)^2\mid\mathcal F_n)=0$ a.s for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. This only happens in the trivial case $X_{n+1}=X_n$ a.s for all $n$.